# Problems with accessing external content as sudo/root

Tags: iptables, sudo

This is a copy of question https://serverfault.com/q/1022610/565687, which might be wrong there (?)

System environment: VM running under Debian 9, firewall is iptables. UFW, etc not installed.

I run into problems when spinning up a kubernetes cluster by executing `sudo kubeadm init`. The call causes a timeout. When I try to access

```
curl https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt
```

this works fine with my local user, but runs as well into timeout if I am using sudo/root. The same is true for communication through port 80/http. I assume the firewall is misconfigured, but I am not sure about this. What do I have to do to enable the access to external content for sudo/root? How can I investigate this issue?

I do have sudo access to the VM but am not an experienced linux admin and the VM as such is managed by another team.

Comment: actually it's not good practice to duplicate questions: you should choose the place where you keep one of them only, and delete the other. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64069#64069 . As for the question, there's no way to answer it without having configurations. If you think it's the iptables firewall, dump the iptables firewall rules (eg: `iptables-save -c`). It could also be about (lack of) NAT. But the Kubernetes integration makes it more difficult of course.